# Bizarre macOS Browser Problem

Tags: macos, bug, web-browsing

I have encountered a rather bizarre macOS problem and I'm wondering if anyone else has seen this in the wild, or has any ideas on how to mitigate it. I've been a Mac admin for a very long time, and I've never before seen anything quite like this.

**The Problem**: Very simply, on certain random websites, the helper/render agent of EVERY web browser immediately goes crazy, reaching and indefinitely remaining at 100% CPU or higher.

**When First Observed**: Approximately January 2024

**What I've Tried**:

- **Clean browser profiles** (this includes no browsing data, no extensions, etc.)
- **Fully Uninstall/reinstall browsers** (except Safari, of course)
- **Different browsers** (I've tried Safari, Edge, Brave, Chrome and Firefox)
- **Different macOS versions** (I've reproduced this on macOS 11 [intel], macOS 12 [M2], macOS 14 [M2])
- **Different user accounts** (I even created a new one just to see what would happen, and there was no difference in the behavior)
- **Different machines** (I've used an M2 MacBook Air, M2 Pro Mac Mini and 2019 16-inch MacBook Pro)
- **Safe Boot** (This one shocked me, but even in Safe Boot with only essential macOS processes running, the behavior is still exactly the same)
- **Clean macOS installs**
- **All of the standard things not listed above which can be found on every blog** (disable hardware acceleration, change random setting X, Y or Z, etc.)

You would think that all of the above would have led to at least some different combination of results, but literally nothing changed. For instance, the M2 Pro Mac Mini is a brand new machine and it does this straight out the box. Based on these variables and results, I can only conclude that this is something within macOS itself. It is clearly not isolated to a particular browser, browning profile, user account, machine or OS.

We know that Edge, Brave and Chrome are essentially using the same Chromium engine, and thus have similar backend processes. It would therefore be logical to assume that if there's some kind of Chromium-based reactivity somewhere within macOS, they'd all display similar behavior. Yet, we see the same behavior on exactly the same websites with Firefox and Safari, two browsers with totally different engines and codebases. It could be something about how the operating system handles these rendering processes, but what could that be and how could it be corrected?

I've attached screenshots of the runaway render processes in Edge, Firefox, Brave and Safari.

Has anyone else observed this? Please let me know if you have any ideas or there's something I haven't thought of.

Thanks for your help!

[image: Brave]

[image: Safari]

[image: Firefox]

[image: Edge]

Comment: Can you giive a specific example of a web page that always reproduces the issue? Also, have you tested on more than one network?

Comment: From the screenshots, (other than the last one,) it looks like you have multiple browsers running concurrently with Edge running in all of them.  I also noticed Avast anti-virus. Try disabling Avast and see what happens. Also, stop running Edge as a test. BTW/ does this cause any system performance degradation?

Comment: Websites that will always reproduce the issue are Google News (the front page, not necessarily every single category page, but many of them) and an article in the NFL section of ESPN.com.

Comment: Yes, I have tested on two different networks and the behavior is the same.

Comment: The reason Edge is running in those particular screenshots is because I was gathering them at the end of my testing, and I already had Edge open since that's the browser I was using to post this article.

Comment: Regarding Avast, I've tried with and without and the results are the same. For example, the M2 Mac Mini was a brand new machine and it had nothing on it, and it displayed the same behavior.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in Safari or Firefox. If you haven't already done so, I suggest you update to the latest version of macOS (14.4). Otherwise, do you have any non-default network settings, such as a VPN or web proxy? As for Avast, like all "anti-virus" and "security" software, it's much worse than useless and should be uninstalled, whether it's causing this problem or not.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. Were you able to reproduce the issue on any of the other browsers (Brave, Edge, Chrome) that I listed? As for the macOS version, I am currently running 14.4 on both my M2 Air and M2 Pro Mini. Though I have tested other versions also. Regarding networking configuration, I'm not using any proxy or VPN, or any other non-standard network settings that I can think of.

Comment: I don't use any other browsers. All of your screenshots seem to show at least two rendering processes spawned by the same browser, with one using high CPU bandwidth and the other not. This doesn't look like a coincidence. Can you reproduce the problem with just one renderer running? If so, then I guess the next step would be to look through the log messages to see whether anything stands out.

Comment: By that do you mean kill one process and see what happens? I think the multiple renderer processes might be normal because of the way that browsers segment their processes, but that's just an assumption.

Comment: Let's focus on your third screenshot. When I open Google News in Firefox, I get only one process named "FirefoxCP Isolated Web Content". What I'm asking you to do is to replicate that configuration. Close all Firefox windows and quit the app, then relaunch it and open Google News -- nothing else. Do you reproduce the problem that way?